# Is it possible to search a layer by name in geemap?

Tags: python, geemap

I'm using geemap, a wrapper of ipyleaflet and folium for earthengine objects.

I'd like to verify if a layer already exist on my map and search for it by it's name, is it possible ?

Comment: See `find_layer` method in `geemap.geemap` module: https://geemap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geemap.html#module-geemap.geemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `find_layer` method as :

```py
m = geemap.Map()

m.find_layer('layerName')
```

Thanks [TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm) for the tip